# accessing datatables data via click binding

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using Jquery DataTables 1.7.6 with JQuery 1.8.6. I am trying to setup a datatable that has a button in one row and then capture the click of that button to move the row to another table. I'm having a problem getting at the data in the DataTable to call the add and remove functions.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var eligibleCreatives = $('#EligibleCreativeTableId').dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bStateSave": true,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "aoColumnDefs": [
                { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [0] },
                { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [3] },
            ],
            "aaSorting": [[1, "asc"]]
        });
        associatedCreatives = $('#AssociatedCreativeTableId').dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bStateSave": true,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "aoColumnDefs": [
                { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [0] },
                { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [3] },
            ],
            "aaSorting": [[1, "asc"]]
        });

        eligibleCreatives.$('tr').click(function () {
            var data = .fnGetData( this );
            // this tells me that eligibleCreatives has no method $

        });


        $('#disassociate-creative').click(function () {
        //I can't get at the actual row node here.
        var data = associatedCreatives.fnGetData($(this).closest('tr')[0]);
        eligibleCreatives.fnAddData(data);
        associatedCreatives.fnDeleteRow(this); 
        return false;
        });
        $('#associate-creative').click(function () {
        var data = associatedCreatives.fnGetData($(this).closest('tr')[0]);
        associatedCreatives.fnAddData(data);
        eligibleCreatives.fnDeleteRow(this);
        return false;
        });

    });
    function fnClickAssociate() {
        $('#AssociatedCreativeTableId').dataTable().fnDeleteRow();
        $('#AssociatedCreativeTableId').dataTable().fnAddData([]);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that fnGetData returns a data object of the contents of a particular row, not the node itself.  But `fnAddData` and `fnDeleteRow` each require the TR node, not the data object.  Two ways to solve this:

**Option 1**: If you're certain that `$(this).closest('tr')[0]` is returning the entire TR element for the row you want, then change the first line of each of your `click` functions to:

```
var data = $(this).closest('tr')[0];
```

This should provide the functions in the next two lines the appropriate TR node to perform the action.

**Option 2**: If you're unsure that the `$(this).closest('tr')[0]` is returning the entire TR element (you can check this by `console.log()`-ing it to see if the appropriate content is returned) then I would consider using Datatable.net's `fnGetPosition` on the TD element that the button is in.  I've found it to be far more flexible and it will always return an element that you can use with `fnAddData` and `fnDeleteRow`.

Good luck!